# Trying to make MS SQL store CRLF

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I get SQL 2008 R2 to store the CR/LF embedded in a string (so 2 paragraphs, or possibly multiple CR/LFs) into a field of a record being inserted programmatically vb.net? Not all records have a CR/LF so I cannot just add them to every record. +Char(13)+char(10) that I could split with a charArrary.

**UPDATE:** This appears to be the actual problem:  the XML parser will convert CR/LF to LF only for consistency. I am **passing data to and from a web service and this seems to be where the CR is being lost**. This is by W3 standard.

[W3.org  Section: 2.11 End-of-Line Handling](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends)

These strings are coming from an Access DB and have the CR/LF already included in a multi-paragraph field of the record. I would like to just pass them straight in, but SQL is converting them to spaces.

In VS Sql Editor the record appears to store 20:20 Hex where the CR/LF should reside. The string actually should have Char(13) & Char(10) or 0x0D0A but it does not.

I see the same results even editing or inserting the record directly via SSMS or the VS SQL Editor. The records were originally submitted via a web service but I have eliminated that for testing. I read that the XML parser will also convert CR/LF to LF only for consistency.

I am not able to show the actual query. But the adapter is built here and populated and passed back to my app via a web service call. This process works for all but the records that have CRLF in them.

```
Dim strConnection As String
strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionStringMyDB").ConnectionString

        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection)

' Access file name
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = dbName

' Table in Access DB           
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tableName  

myConnection.Open()

' Create the DataAdapter
Dim myDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand

' Populate the DataSet and close the connection
Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)
myConnection.Close()

Return myDataSet
```

Processsing in my app after assigning the dataset to a table.

```
For Each row As DataRow In myTable.Rows
    Dim stringVal As String = row(columnName).ToString()

    ' Eventually added this to see that the row was adding 2 spaces after the carriage return
    Dim cstringVal() As Char = stringVal.ToCharArray
    Dim csearchValue() As Char = searchValue.ToCharArray

   ' Also added this code
       Dim line_array1 As [String]() = stringVal.Split(vbCr & vbLf.ToCharArray())
       Dim line_array2 As [String]() = searchValue.Split(vbCr & vbLf.ToCharArray())

    ' line_Array2 consistently IDs the vbCRLF, line_array1 never does.


    ' Originally tried
    If row(columnName) = searchValue Then
        return True
    End If

    ' Tried this
    If stringVal = searchValue Then
        Return True
    End If

    ' And this
     If String.Compare(stringVal, searchValue, False) = 0 Then
        Return True
     End If
   Next
Return False
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to read back your values and checked if the CRLF is there or not?

Comment: Yes, they are not there only space. I have populated a charArray to confirm the results. I used a Sql DataAdpater to query the SQL table, and if it is suppose to convert the values back to CR/LF it has not yet done so. I will update the post with code.

Comment: CRLF is Char(13)&Char(10)

Comment: Updated. Had written them backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is UNICODE. By my experience there is no problem with storing `CRLF`, but there can be problem UNICODE <-> ASCII.

Please try

```
Dim cmd as SQLCommand
cmd.CommandText = "insert into MyTable(fld) values (N'" + VariableContainingCRLF +"')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Or

```
Dim cmd as SQLCommand
cmd.CommandText = "insert into MyTable(fld) values (@param)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = VariableContainingCRLF
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Letter `N` before a string or `NVarChar` is crucial. `DataAdapter` introduces just other confusing layer.

Comment: Well the problem is exactgly the DataAdapter and comparing the string. I read through a series of Access database tables to see if the strings match. The DataAdapter does not represent the string as it was stored. This is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: @marc11h: It can be useful to add sample of code you are using to read and write data.

Comment: Sure what would you like to see, this is a simple SQL DataAdapter that i dump to a table. Then iterate through using the code above. I can show the earlier part but it pretty straight forward. Stand by.

Comment: FYI, the insert is done through a Table Adapter. Might be tough to show the code as it is all auto generated.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing data storage and data display and editing.

I just verified that SQL Server does store CRLF in a VARCHAR field:

```
insert into MyTable (VarcharField)
values ('A'+CHAR(13)+'B')
, ('A'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'B')
, ('A
B')
```

by checking the ASCII() codes of the inserted strings

```
SELECT VarcharField, LEN(VarcharField),
  , ASCII(substring(VarcharField, 2, 1))
  , ASCII(substring(VarcharField, 3, 1))
FROM MyTable
```

The CR and CRLF are *displayed* as spaces, but they are still stored as 0x0D and 0x0A, or 13 and 10.

Comment: I would tend to agree, but when you try to populate a SQL DataAdapter and compare the fields they are still spaces. See my code above. Which is why I would like to force the CRLF if possible, or find another acceptable work around.